# How to send Ctrl+C signal to a console process created with CreateNoWindow flag

Tags: vb.net, process, signals

If I use `Process.Kill()`, the process is killed. However, I would like to terminate it.

I tried with `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(ConsoleCtrlEvent.CTRL_C, Process.Id)` API, without success.

If I set `False` to `CreateNoWindow` flag, when I send Ctrl+C from keyboard, the program says `"Caught signal: 2; Terminating"`. So it wait a "2" signal to terminate.

How can I do that?

Comment: Raymond Chen [wrote about something similar](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/07/06/10183368.aspx) recently.

Comment: That's the same problem. But it seems that he didn't find the solution, did he?

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution. I will try to describe it for you:

When you write the application which wraps the entire console - console into can't receive control codes for some reason (question going to Microsoft), but the console can still  receive those events. How? From an external app.

This is the code for cas.exe

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleAppStopper
{
    class cas
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            if (args.Length < 2)
            {
                Help ();
                return;
            }
            int processId = int.Parse (args[0]);
            ConsoleCtrlEvent CtrlEvent = (ConsoleCtrlEvent)int.Parse(args[1]);

            FreeConsole ();
            AttachConsole (processId);
            GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent (CtrlEvent, 0);
        }

        static void Help()
        {
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;
            Console.WriteLine ("Console Application Eventer(Stopper)");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.WriteLine ("cas.exe ProcessId ControlEvent");
            Console.WriteLine ("Events:");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine ("\tCTRL_C - 0");
            Console.WriteLine ("\tCTRL_BREAK - 1");
            Console.WriteLine ("\tCTRL_LOGOFF - 5");
            Console.ResetColor ();
        }

        public enum ConsoleCtrlEvent
        {
            CTRL_C = 0, // From wincom.h
            CTRL_BREAK = 1,
            CTRL_CLOSE = 2,
            CTRL_LOGOFF = 5,
            CTRL_SHUTDOWN = 6
        }
        [DllImport ("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern bool GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent( ConsoleCtrlEvent sigevent,
        int dwProcessGroupId );

        [DllImport ("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern bool FreeConsole();

        [DllImport ("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern bool AttachConsole( int dwProcessId ); 
    }
}
```

and how to use it:

```
public void SendConsoleEvent( ConsoleCtrlEvent ev )
{
    if (!Running)
        return;

    try
    {
        String current_dir = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        String stopper = "cas.exe";
        String args = pr.Id + " " + (int)ev;

        CommandExecutor ex = new CommandExecutor (null, null);
        ex.Start (current_dir, stopper, args);
        // sometimes stop prevent CAS do work. just throw cas and forget about
        //Timer.DelayCall (TimeSpan.FromSeconds (10), ex.Stop);
        //ex.Stop ();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log ("SendConsoleEvent: " + e.ToString ());
    }
}
```

Here, `CommandExecutor` is my threaded wrapper around Process.
pr.Id is the ID of previously started using Process console (where we need to send our CTRL_C or other events